# Enemy collision in Ursina

Tags: python, ursina

I'm making a game in Ursina and I want to print "true" or "false" (like a boolean). This is because the game I am making needs collision for the entities. I have looked for a solution but I couldn't find anything. How can I detect collisions in Ursina?

```
from ursina import *
import random


#variables
speed = 0.05
number_of_pokemon = 10

app = Ursina()

#textures
player_texture = load_texture('pokemon orange assets/player.png')
pokemon_texture1 = load_texture('pokemon orange assets/pokemon.png')
pokemon_texture2 = load_texture('pokemon orange assets/pokemon2.png')
pokemon_texture3 = load_texture('pokemon orange assets/pokemon3.png')
grass_texture = load_texture('pokemon orange assets/grass.png')
textbox_texture = load_texture('pokemon orange assets/textbox.png')
missingno_texture = load_texture('pokemon orange assets/missingno.png')

pokemontextures = [pokemon_texture1, pokemon_texture2, pokemon_texture3]

#entitys: pokemon(s), player, textbox, battles
player = Entity(model = 'cube', texture = player_texture, scale = (1,1,0), position = 
(0,0,-0.1))
#textbox = Entity(model ='cube', texture = textbox_texture, scale = (5,1,0), position = 
(0,-3,0))

#spawns pokemon
number = random.uniform(0,100)
if(number == 100):
    for i in range (100):
         pokemon = Entity(model ='cube', texture = missingno_texture, scale = (1,2,0), 
      position = (random.uniform(-10,10),random.uniform(-10,10),random.uniform(-10,10)))
else:
    for i in range(number_of_pokemon):
        pokemon = Entity(model ='cube', texture = random.choice(pokemontextures), scale = (1.5,1.5,0), position = (random.uniform(-5,5),random.uniform(-4,4),-0.1))


#spawns grass
for y in range(20):   
    for x in range(20):
        grass = Entity(model ='cube', texture = grass_texture, scale = (1,1,0), position = (x - 10,y - 10,0))

#movement
def update():
    player.x += held_keys['d'] * speed 
    player.x -= held_keys['a'] * speed 
    player.y += held_keys['w'] * speed 
    player.y -= held_keys['s'] * speed 
           


app.run()
```

Answer (score 2):

Set a [Collider](https://www.ursinaengine.org/cheat_sheet.html#Collider) and check if your entity intersects with another one:

```py
player = Entity(model='cube',
                texture=player_texture,
                scale=(1, 1, 0),
                position=(0, 0, -0.1),
                collider='box') # <-- do the same for all pokemon entities

hit_info = player.intersects()
if hit_info.hit:
    print(hit_info.entity)
```

Comment: thank you for explaining :D

Comment: @LucasVuijk if I have solved your problem, please consider upvoting and/or marking the answer as accepted to complete the QA cycle.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a simple Boolean value, Jan's answer is the best.

But if you want to get specifically which side of the player is colliding with an Entity, (like to prevent them from walking through walls) you can use raycasting. You could make raycasts going out from the player's position on all sides, like Ursina's FirstPersonController does.

Here's an example:

```
from ursina import *

app = Ursina()
EditorCamera()

player = Entity(model='cube', scale=(1, 2, 1), y=1, color=color.blue)
speed = 0.1

testPlane = Entity(model='plane', scale=10, collider='mesh')
testObject = Entity(model='cube', scale=(1, 2, 1), position=(2, 1, 2), collider='box', color=color.red)

collided = {}
def update():
    for i in ['forward', 'back', 'left', 'right', 'up', 'down']: # iterates through all sides and creates a raycast
        if i in ['forward', 'back']: # Makes sure the 'hitbox' scale matches the player's scale
            distance = player.scale_z/2
        if i in ['left', 'right']:
            distance = player.scale_x/2
        if i in ['up', 'down']:
            distance = player.scale_y/2

        collided[i] = raycast(player.world_position, getattr(player, i), distance, ignore=[player])

    # The "collided" object should now include boolean values of collisions from all sides.

    # Here's an example on how to use this:

    if held_keys['w']:
        if not collided['forward']:
            player.position += player.forward*speed

    if held_keys['s']:
        if not collided['back']:
            player.position += player.back*speed

    if held_keys['a']:
        if not collided['left']:
            player.position += player.left*speed

    if held_keys['d']:
        if not collided['right']:
            player.position += player.right*speed

app.run()
```

I tested this to make sure it worked